# Можно ли исключить из синхронизации отдельные папки в google диск?

Tags: google-drive

Например чтобы всякий мусор вроде папок node_modules не загружался по 15 дней блокируя саму синхронизацию.

А если нет, то есть ли аналогичные сервисы где это можно?

Comment: Git пробовали пользоваться? Как вариант можно использовать приватные репозитории))

Comment: Можно, но удобней было бы скидывать весь свой код(который может быть и вне репозиториев) в 1 место, как в архив.